# how can I check the value of the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable?

Tags: django

`echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` doesn't return anything, even though from reading the tutorial my understanding is that this environment variable should have been set.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial doesn't say that. It says that when you run `manage.py`, it takes care of setting that variable within the project's process. It doesn't export it to the base shell - what would be the point?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how django works at every step of the way, that's all.

Comment: does this mean that the value of $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE will be different for different django projects?